# Why is the outcome of problem 23 of project Euler wrong?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve problem 23 of project Euler (a website with math puzzles). Problem 23 is this:

[image]

I wrote some code in Python, but my outcome is wrong and I have no idea why it is wrong. Can somebody help me out and tell me what part in my code is wrong?

Explanation code: In the first 8 lines I try to get all the abundant numbers and put them in `lst1`. In the second 8 lines I go over all the abundant numbers in `lst1` and get all possible combinations of 2 abundant numbers and add those 2 up. The sum of this put I in `lst2`. In the last few lines, I go over all the numbers from `12 to 28123` and see if they match `lst2`. If they match it is possible to write the number as the sum of two abundant numbers. If they don't match I add them to `lst3`. Then I print the sum of `lst3`. The outcome is: `395465560`.

```
lst1 = []
for i in range(1, 28123):
    total = 0
    for j in range(1, i // 2 + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            total += j
    if total > i:
        lst1.append(i)
lst2 = []
for x in lst1:
    for y in lst1:
        total = x + y
        if total > 28123:
            break
        else:
            lst2.append(total)
lst3 = []
for z in range(12, 28123 + 1):
    if z != lst2:
        lst3.append(z)
print(sum(lst3))
```

Comment: What is wrong about the code? Could you include the expected output?

Comment: you can use a dict  to do memorization of number divisors

Comment: The expected output must be: 4179871

Comment: @sahasrara62 A dict instead of a list? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: what i mean was, for example you know divisor sum of 12 ->1 +2+3+6 =16 , so you save this info in dictionary and when you want to find the divisior some of 24 -> 1+2+3+4+6+12 , instead of calculating whole you can just do   -> dic[12]+12 ie 16+12 =36 , like that t his way you can do little performance boost

Comment: Ooh I see. I will try to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just check the output of:

```py
print(sum(range(12, 28123 + 1)))
```

you will get `395465560`. So you are summing up all numbers in this range. And why? Because of this mistake in the last lines of code:

```py
lst3 = []
for z in range(12, 28123 + 1):
    # if z != lst2:
    if z not in lst2:
        lst3.append(z)
print(sum(lst3))
```

Also, you can make the same code faster utilizing `itertools` and sets.

```py
import itertools

abundant_numbers = []
abundant_range = range(1, 28123+1)
for i in abundant_range:
    total = 1
    for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            total += j
    if total > i:
        abundant_numbers.append(i)

sum_of_abundant_numbers = [sum(p) for p in itertools.product(abundant_numbers, abundant_numbers)]
abundant_numbers_2 = [a for a in sum_of_abundant_numbers if a <= 28123]

k1 = set(abundant_range)
print(sum(k1 - set(abundant_numbers_2)))
```

the above can be even further reduced.

Comment: Ooh yeah, I see it now. One little mistake ;). Now I must my code more efficient, 'cause it's taking too long. But, thanks for your help!

Comment: I edited my post, so you can see a bit faster implementation. Play a bit more to reduce some redundant steps.

Comment: Actually your code is not right. Your outcome is `4179806` and it need to be `4179871`.

Comment: But I have found the issue. At the end of your code you do `set(adbundant_range)`. Your `abundant_range` starts at `12`, but you can't write the numbers below `12` as the sum of 2 abundants. The question is about the sum of ints which cannot be writen as the sum of 2 abundants

Comment: No worries, it works correctly now, I edited it. We can set the default range to start from 1, and not 12. In that case, the answer will pick up the sum of all numbers below 12 (as they are not abundant) and it won't add those numbers to the abundant list. Check the answer now.

Comment: Also, your question was `why` your code is not producing the correct output, and not `how` to solve this question. I gave you a correct answer on the specific detail regarding why. Also, check my code again, I edited it

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah I know. I didn't really want to know how to solve it, but what the mistake was.